# Error in HTA with fileopen

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I'm using a script from Rob van der Woude for the open file dialog (top post from [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_fileopen.php)) which is apparently supposed to work in HTA but I get an error saying:

> "ActiveX component can't create object: 'UserAccounts.CommonDialog'"

Comment: Read under code snippet: _Summarized: Works in Windows XP only_

Comment: Perhaps [this my answer could help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28672540/3439404)... It's a basic small HTA sample opening either file or folder dialogue... Also I found a simple customization of the Win32 open file dialog that enables it to be used to select either a file or a folder. Copyright (C) 2010 Scott Wisniewski; he says [_It's free, and in the public domain. Use it as you see fit_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/514368/3439404). HTH.

Answer (score 2):

This function may be helps you !

**BrowseForFile.vbs**

```
   '************************************************************************************** 
    ' GetFileDlg() And GetFileDlgBar() by omen999 - may 2014 - http://omen999.developpez.com
    ' Universal Browse for files function  
    ' compatibility : all versions windows and IE - supports start folder, filters and title
    ' note : the global size of the parameters cannot exceed 191 chars for GetFileDlg and 227 chars for GetFileDlgBar
    '**************************************************************************************
    Function GetFileDlg(sIniDir,sFilter,sTitle)
     GetFileDlg=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<object id=d classid=clsid:3050f4e1-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b></object><script>moveTo(0,-9999);function window.onload(){var p=/[^\0]*/;new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(p.exec(d.object.openfiledlg('" & sIniDir & "',null,'" & sFilter & "','" & sTitle & "')));close();}</script><hta:application showintaskbar=no />""").StdOut.ReadAll
    End Function

    Function GetFileDlgBar(sIniDir,sFilter,sTitle)
     GetFileDlgBar=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<object id=d classid=clsid:3050f4e1-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b></object><script>moveTo(0,-9999);function window.onload(){var p=/[^\0]*/;new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(p.exec(d.object.openfiledlg('" & sIniDir & "',null,'" & sFilter & "','" & sTitle & "')));close();}</script>""").StdOut.ReadAll
    End Function

    ' sample test
    sIniDir = "C:\Windows\Fonts\*"
    sFilter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|Microsoft Word (*.doc;*.docx)|*.doc;*.docx|Adobe pdf (*.pdf)|*.pdf|"
    sTitle = "GetFileDlg by omen999 2014 - omen999.developpez.com"

    ' (sIniDir + sFilter + sTitle) size doesn't exceed 191 chars (227 for GetFileDlgBar)
    ' MsgBox Len(Replace(sIniDir,"\","\\")) + Len(sFilter) + Len(sTitle)

    ' sIniDir must be conformed to the javascript syntax
    rep = GetFileDlg(Replace(sIniDir,"\","\\"),sFilter,sTitle)
    MsgBox rep & vbcrlf & Len(rep)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JosefZ mentioned in the comments, the `UserAccounts.CommonDialog` library is available in Windows XP only. However, there are other ways to display an `"Open File"` dialog.

The `Shell.Application` object has a [`BrowserForFolder()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065(v=vs.85).aspx) function that, by default, displays a dialog asking you to select a folder. However, you can configure this dialog in a number of ways by using combinations of the [`ulFlags` values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For example, if you include the `BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES` flag, the dialog will also show files in addition to folders.

Here's a minimal example showing how you can have the `BrowserForFolder` dialog to display files and prompt the user to select a file:

```
' BROWSEINFO Flags...
Const BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON  = &H0200   ' Hide the [New Folder] button
Const BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES = &H4000   ' Show files in addition to folders

' ShellSpecialFolderConstants...
Const ssfDESKTOP = 0 

Dim objStartIn, objFile
With CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    ' Specify the folder the dialog should start in...
    Set objStartIn = .NameSpace(ssfDESKTOP)   ' Start in a special folder
    Set objStartIn = .NameSpace("c:\")        ' Or, start in custom path

    ' Args = (parent window, dialog title, flags, start folder)
    Set objFile = .BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a file:", _
        BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES Or BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON, objStartIn)

End With

If Not objFile Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo objFile.Self.Path
End If
```

Of course, the user *could* still select a folder. There's no way to stop that from happening. But you can check the item returned to see if it's a folder and prompt them to reselect (perhaps in a loop).

```
If objFile.Self.IsFolder Then
    ' Invalid
End If
```