# HTA file save dialog instead of open dialog

Tags: html, batch-file, hta

I want to use a file input to open a save dialog instead of a open dialog. This will allow the user to give output locations. in my application.

My HTA code is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="objTest" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTATest"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>

<script>
function sync()
{
  var InputTextbox = document.getElementById('InputTextbox');
  var OutputTextbox = document.getElementById('OutputTextbox');
  OutputTextbox.value = InputTextbox.value;
}
</script>

</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

    Sub TestSub
        Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Shell.run "h:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "& InputTextbox.Value & " " & OutputTextbox.Value
    End Sub

</SCRIPT>



<body bgcolor="buttonface">
<p><font face="verdana" color="red">VOB to MP4 Converter</font></p>
 <p>
    Input : <input type="file" name="InputTextbox" size="30"><P>
    Output: <input type="text" name="OutputTextbox" size="30"
    ><font>Please change file extention to required format</font><br>

    <input id=runbutton  type="button" value="Convert!" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub">
</p>
</body>
```

Thank in Advance

Comment: Please check if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28672540/3439404) to [VBScript file or folder selection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28632270/3439404) could help?

Comment: What does this have to do with batch files?

Answer (score 4):

There's no native Windows Scripting Host interface for the "Save As" dialog [from what I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482535/1683264).  Easiest way I've found to produce the dialog is to borrow from .NET.  PowerShell works with .NET objects pretty easily.  Here's a Batch / PowerShell hybrid script that will open the Save As dialog, forcing a .mp4 extension:

```perl
<# : batch portion
@powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
@exit /b
: end batch / begin PowerShell #>
add-type -as System.windows.forms
$save = New-Object Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$save.initialDirectory = $pwd.path
$save.filter = "MP4 files (*.mp4)|*.mp4"
$save.ShowHelp = $true
[void]$save.ShowDialog()
$save.filename
```

With this in mind, you can write the script to %temp% and execute it using [Shell.Exec()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx) in order to capture the STDOUT within your HTA script functions.  Once the script is completed, the temporary batch file can be deleted.  See the `saveDlg()` function in the following example.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="objTest" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTATest"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>

<textarea style="display: none" id="save_bat">
<# : batch portion
@powershell -noprofile -window hidden "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
@exit
: end batch / begin PowerShell #>
add-type -as System.windows.forms
$save = New-Object Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$save.initialDirectory = $pwd.path
$save.filter = "MP4 files (*.mp4)|*.mp4"
$save.ShowHelp = $true
[void]$save.ShowDialog()
$save.filename
</textarea>

<script language="JavaScript">
function saveDlg() {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
        shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"),
        temp = shell.Environment("Process")("temp"),
        batfile = fso.createTextFile(temp + "\\save.bat", true),
        saveLoc;

    batfile.write(document.getElementById("save_bat").value);
    batfile.close();

    var proc = shell.Exec(temp + "\\save.bat");
    while (!proc.Status && !saveLoc) {
        saveLoc = proc.StdOut.ReadLine();
        proc.Terminate();
    }
    fso.DeleteFile(temp + "\\save.bat", 1);
    return saveLoc;
}

function goBabyGo() {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
    shell.run("h:\\tools\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i "
        + document.getElementById("InputTextbox").value
        + ' '
        + document.getElementById('OutputTextbox').value
    );
}
</script>

<body bgcolor="buttonface">
<p><font face="verdana" color="red">VOB to MP4 Converter</font></p>
 <p>
    Input : <input type="file" id="InputTextbox" size="30" />
</p>
<p>
    Output: <input type="text" id="OutputTextbox" size="30" readonly />
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('OutputTextbox').value = saveDlg()">Save As...</button>
</p>
<p>
    <input id=runbutton type="button" value="Convert!" name="run_button"  onClick="goBabyGo()" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```