# how to detect when cancel upload file on mobile by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, mobile, upload

Im making upload image from mobile to website. When user click on upload button i will disable "save" button until image is uploaded. But when user cancel upload after click on upload button, i dont know how to detect that event to enable "save" button. I found this solution [How to detect when cancel is clicked on file input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628544/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input) 
But It's only work on desktop. On mobile, cancel action is total different.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do that, instead of disabling the save button, is to hide the save button when user clicks on upload. When user clicks on cancel button, you can display save button again.

Comment: when we upload file on moblie there is no cancel button. touching outside of dialog or tab on back button is cancel action.