# How to detect file input cancel on Android chrome browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-video

I know several questions were asked on file input cancel - here I am looking for the same on Android and iOS device browsers.

Based on the answers given for the below Question

[How to detect when cancel is clicked on file input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628544/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input)

I tried all below solutions

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/T3Vwz/
 http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/6h2r7/1/
 http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/6h2r7/2/
```

But none of them working in Android device browsers.However working on desktop browsers.

debugging results clarifies that `document.body.onfocus` will never get called on Android browsers also `fileSelectEle.onchange` will never get called by simply clicking the file input.

My Question -
is there any universal solution which works for most of the Android/iOS device browsers?

any workaround for this?