# Close image browse window event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform some operation when user close the image browse window. How can i know that browse image window is closed without image select in JavaScript? 
I search for this on internet but didn't get any answer. Is it possible to get the close event in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628544/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when cancel is clicked on file input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628544/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input)

Comment: Yes, but it is not working on my site that's why i asked here